# MySql: Consolidating rows with matching records

Tags: mysql, sql

My table has a list of users with Items associated to them. I hope to be able to consolidate the items field into a list or create another column if the row has a matching User/email.

I have the following structure with in the MySQL table:

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦════════════╗
║     ID    ║   User_ID   ║     Item    ║    Date     ║    User     ║   Email    ║  
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬════════════╣
║     1     ║     1       ║   Laptop 1  ║  30th Nov   ║    John     ║ J@test.com ║
║     2     ║     2       ║   Laptop 3  ║  12th Nov   ║    Emma     ║ e@test.com ║
║     3     ║     2       ║   Camera 3  ║  12th Nov   ║    Emma     ║ e@test.com ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩════════════╝
```

I am very new to SQL but i think i would need to use some type of transpose field to a column function?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What output do you expect? And are you using sql-server or mysql? Can't be both

Comment: Hi Arion thank you for the response, i am using MySQL    I hope to only have one row returned if the user fields match. For example: Emma would have both Laptop 3 & Camera 3 as they have a matching User.     Not sure of the best way of getting this result, either a new column or concat the items into a list?

Comment: Just a side remark: Your database design is not good it seems. What would it mean when user_id 2 would be Emma in one record and Ingrid on the other? Or if the e-mail addresses differed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `group_concat()`.  Personally, I would use `user_id`, rather than `user/email`.  or, perhaps all three together.  Something like this:

```
select user_id, user, email, group_concat(item) as items
from table t
group by user_id, user, email;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! The group_concat creates a comma-separated list of items.